# Using Sin-1 or inverse sin in python

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, trigonometry

Here is my code:

```
# point of intersection between opposite and hypotenuse

x,y  =    pygame.mouse.get_pos()


# using formula for length of line

lenline1 = (x-x)**2 + (300-y)**2
lenline2 = (x-700)**2 + (y-300)**2

opposite = math.sqrt(lenline1)

adjacent = math.sqrt(lenline2)

# Converting length of lines to angle

PQ = opposite/adjacent
k = math.sin(PQ)
j = math.asin(k)

print(j)
```

I'm not getting the results I expected, although after messing around with it I got close but it wasn't quite right. Could someone please tell me what I'm doin wrong. I have two lines:
opposite and adjacent
And I wish to get the angle using the inverse of sin. What am I doing wrong. I'm only a beginner so  don't give too detailed info. I can't imagine this is hard to do.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't literally have `|l1|` in your code...that would be a syntax error. `^` in Python isn't exponentiation, it's xor; use `**` for exponentiation. If your code runs without a syntax error, then you should post your real code instead of this pseudocode.

Comment: I understand this I just have it like this for the moment so people understand it is the length of the line

Comment: I would prefer if you just posted your code, and explained the variables in your question.

Comment: If you're actually calling these 'opposite' and 'adjacent', and its a right-angled triangle, then your angle is found as `math.atan2(y_diff, x_diff)`. But then again, I don't know what angle you are trying to find!

Comment: Am tring to find angle where hypotenuse and adjacent meet. 
@nneonneo: I have edited my script, maybe it makes more sense now, I have labelled them now

Comment: If I'm reading this right, line1 is (x,y) to (x,300), and line2 is (x,y) to (700,300). But in that case, line2 is the hypotenuse, not the adjacent. This makes your original choice of `asin` correct except when x=700 or y=300.

Comment: P.S. If that's your *real actual code*, then you need to change `^` to `**`; see my first comment. That might just fix it.

Comment: Those are precisely the two lines I have. So with this information have you any idea where my code is wrong, leading to false numbers. Thanks for this btw.

Answer (score 3):

To find the angle between two lines, use the following relation:

```
cos(angle) = (l1 dot l2) / (|l1| |l2|)
```

That is,

```
dotproduct = l1x * l2x + l1y * l2y
lenproduct = |l1| * |l2|
angle = acos(dotproduct / lenproduct)
```

where l1x, l1y are the x,y components of the line l1.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with the `k` computation, its meaningless.

```
j = math.asin(PQ)
```

However, this only works for right-angled triangles and you have to appropriate side lengths in the right places. In general this will not work and you need to use the [dot product method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: Actually, mathematically, `j = PQ` would be correct...he just calculated j = asin(sin(PQ)).

Comment: I get a math domain error from this. It could be a problem where I'm getting the length of the line although I'm following fairly simple formulas and it looks right.

Comment: Could the code leading up to PQ be incorrect? I only followed the basic trig. formulas.

Comment: @DennisCallanan There are limitations for `math.asin` being appropriate. See the answer of @nneonneo for the correct general way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to find the angle of the triangle (700,300), (x,300), (x,y). You're making it much more complicated than it needs to be. the length of the hypotenuse is `math.hypot((700-x),(300-y))` and the angle is `math.atan2((700-x), (300-y))`.