# Using asin, sin-1, inverse of sin, trigonometry in python

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Sin-1 or inverse sin in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435856/using-sin-1-or-inverse-sin-in-python)

Here is my code:

```
# point of intersection between opposite and hypotenuse

x,y  =    pygame.mouse.get_pos()


# using formula for length of line

lenline1 = (x-x)**2 + (300-y)**2
lenline2 = (x-700)**2 + (y-300)**2

opposite = math.sqrt(lenline1)

adjacent = math.sqrt(lenline2)

# Converting length of lines to angle

PQ = opposite/adjacent
k = math.sin(PQ)
j = math.asin(k)

print(j)
```

I'm not getting the results I expected, although after messing around with it I got close but it wasn't quite right. Could someone please tell me what I'm doin wrong. I have two lines: opposite and adjacent And I wish to get the angle using the inverse of sin. What am I doing wrong. I'm only a beginner so don't give too detailed info. I can't imagine this is hard to do.

Thanks.

I am trying to get the angle where the hypotenuse and adjacent meet !!

Comment: Please don't repeat your questions.

Comment: Don't re-ask the same question.  If you feel like your previous version of this question wasn't accurate or didn't get the responses you wanted, edit it and make it better.

Comment: Also "(x-x)" in "lenline1 = (x-x)^2 + (300-y)^2" is probably not what you want, because it's always 0 ;-)

Comment: Exponentiation in Python is written `**` not `^`.

Comment: @septi: It also might just be a way of documenting that the line goes from (x,y) to (x,300), i.e. that the x coordinate does not change.

Comment: @nneonneo yea you're right, that's why I wrote "probably" ; )

Answer (score -1):

`^` in Python means exclusive or, not exponentiation. If you want exponentiation, use the `**` operator.

Comment: I changed "^" to "**" and yes, it made a difference but still not the right answer. As Septi stated (x-x)**2 returns as 0 no matter what. Maybe this is an error I made using the formula, but I can't be sure.